# Get Month of out System Datetime

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have data in my database that contains the following filed.

```
Id | name | RegDate
1    John   2014-09-05
2    mike   2014-09-05
3    Duke   2014-10-14
```

I'm performing a query to count the number of values where the reg date is equal 09. 09 is the month of the date.

I'm trying to convert the date I store in db in a month format then get a new month of a system date to get the result.

Here is my query in linq but it keeps on giving the wrong count. please I need your help. thanks.

```
var CountPassengers = (from c in db.CountPassengerManifestViews where c.DepartureDate.Month.ToString()== DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MM")  select c).Count();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where c.DepartureDate.Month == DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month
```

You don't compare string representation, because it's already converted into DateTime object, so it doesn't make sense to do it your way. This simple change should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would *strongly* recommend that you get rid of all the string manipulation. Your query doesn't conceptually have anything to do with strings, so why are you introducing them into the code?

You can write your query as:

```
int currentMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1).Month;

var passengerCount = db.CountPassengerManifestViews
                       .Count(c => c.DepartureDate.Month == currentMonth);
```

However, that will *only* filter by month - it won't filter by month and year, so if you have data from 2013 that would be included too. It's more likely that you want something like:

```
DateTime oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
DateTime start = oneMonthAgo.AddDays(1 - oneMonthAgo.Day);
DateTime end = start.AddMonths(1);

var passengerCount = db.CountPassengerManifestViews
                       .Count(c => c.DepartureDate >= start &&
                                   c.DepartureDate < end);
```

That way you're expressing a range of dates, rather than just extracting the month part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer all, you guys are right. the ToString is the problem. its now solved. thanks again

Comment: @HarunaAdo: Well that doesn't *really* solve the problem, unless you're trying to include everything in this month of the year across all time... While that *may* be what you're trying to do, it's slightly odd. (I'd also strongly recommend using `Count` with a predicate instead of a pointless query expression followed by a call to `Count()`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var CountPassengers = (from c in db.CountPassengerManifestViews 
                       where c.DepartureDate.Month.ToString("MM")== DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("MM")  
                       select c).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are doing the string manipulation but if you only want to compare the month part of the two dates then do the following:

```
where c.DepartureDate.Month== DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code compares Month.ToString() that gives "9" with ToString("MM") that gives "09".
You could also improve by removing ".ToString()":

```
 int lastMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month;
 var CountPassengers = (from c in db.CountPassengerManifestViews where c.DepartureDate.Month == lastMonth select c).Count();
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
var month = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1).Month;            
var CountPassengers = db.CountPassengerManifestViews.Count(c => c.DepartureDate.Month == month);
```